# Conversion of list of dictionaries to JSON config file with configparser

Tags: python, json, configparser

I have the following list of dictionaries

```
dicts =  [{
    "name": "Header1",
    "names": ["query1","query2","query3","query4","query5","query6"]
}, {
    "name":"Header2",
    "names": ["query1","query2","query3","query4","query5"]
}]
```

I convert it to JSON file with the following code

```
with open("testing.json","w") as j:
      json.dump(dicts,j,indent = 2)
```

and I get the following result

```
[
  {
    "name": "Header1",
    "names": [
      "query1",
      "query2",
      "query3",
      "query4",
      "query5",
      "query6"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Header2",
    "names": [
      "query1",
      "query2",
      "query3",
      "query4",
      "query5"
    ]
  }
]
```

I was wondering whether I could achieve the above result with the config parser.

I run the following code

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.add_section("Queries")
config.set("Queries","Header1",["query1","query2","query3","query4","query5","query6"])
```

and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: option values must be strings
```

Comment: `configparser` is for INI files. You can't create JSON with it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? what's wrong with `json.dump`?

Comment: What's would the point of doing it with `ConfigParser` be?

Comment: Ok, I saw the difference and what INI format is. I want to transform it into JSON so configparser is out of the question

Answer (score 1):

convert the `list` to string

```
import configparser

lst = ["query1","query2","query3","query4","query5","query6"]
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.add_section("Queries")
config.set("Queries","Header1",",".join(lst))

print(config)
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that INI files do not have a list datatype, and that upon reading the file, the value must be **manually** converted to a list again.

Comment: I agree with the comment.